# Streaming download with axlsx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, axlsx

How to do streaming download with axlsx gem. I need a way to download huge file in chunks. The time it will take more than 5 minutes and I don't want to use any background jobs for this task. I am using [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/caxlsx/axlsx_rails) gem

The approach which I came up with

```
def download
  headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xlsx"  
  headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{file_name}\""  
  headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no' 
  headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache" 
  headers.delete("Content-Length")  
  @result =  FetchRecord.new(data)
  response.status = 200
  render xlsx: "file_download.xlsx.axlsx", filename: "#{file_name.camelize}.xlsx",locals: {result: @result}
end
```

The above solution is not working for me. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def download
  @result =  FetchRecord.new(data)
  @file = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"]).render(handlers: [:axlsx], template: "model_name/download.xlsx", locals: {result: @result})
  respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx { send_file @file, disposition: "attachment", filename: "file_download.xlsx"}
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Do you really what to generate the file triggerd by your users? This could open an DOS Attack vector. You should consider a background job preparing those files.

An the rest should be handled in you webserver, not by rails or rack.

Comment: In my case I don't have to worry about DOS Attack vector

Comment: Why voting it down? DOS is a problem here cause axlsx will consume a lot of RAM an block a process or thread depending on your implementation.

You should at least consider a ExcelCacheFile Class with a fetch_or_generate method for this.